# Shared Preferences not setting correctly (using async await)

Tags: flutter, sharedpreferences

I am using shared preferences for Flutter but it does not seem to work properly.Here is the code simplified:

```dart
final listOfTopics = prefs.getStringList('outofstocktopics') ?? [];

  print('Length before: ${listOfTopics.length}');

final List<String> test = [];
  await prefs.setStringList('outofstocktopics', test);
  final listOfTopics2 = prefs.getStringList('outofstocktopics') ?? [];

  print('Length after: ${listOfTopics2.length}');
```

I am testing this and both give me '1' in the console log. However, I clearly put an empty array in it. And I await for it to be done.

How is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

You need to reload to be able to get the latest:

https://pub.dev/documentation/shared_preferences/latest/shared_preferences/SharedPreferences/reload.html

Comment: Does that mean I need to use prefs.reload() everytime I want to use shared Preferences?

Comment: that shouldn't be necessary. As it also states there, only for when shared preferences are set in native code

Comment: even though documentation suggests that this is for only native code, I found this to be true about read after writes unfortunately. this may be related. https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/95013

Comment: What do you mean by native code? I write it in Flutter :P

Comment: I mean the second paragraph in the doc link in my answer.

Comment: You mean this piece of code is native code? 
storeValue(String value) async {
    final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    await prefs.setString("myKey", value);
}